# How to pass URL Dynamically from xml using Attribute in Objective c

Tags: ios, xml, xcode

How to pass URL Dynamically from xml using Attribute in Objective c and then i want to store url in matches string.

```
NSString * home= @"http://sports.xyz.rss/rss.aspx";
    MSXMLParser * homenew=[[MSXMLParser alloc]init];
    [homenew parseWithURLString:home FileName:@"file" xmlType:@"MATCHES"];
    NSMutableDictionary * mainDict = [MSDataDictionary newsDictionary];
    for (int i=0; i<=[mainDict count]; i++) 
    {
        NSString * theKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        NSMutableDictionary * itemDict = [mainDict objectForKey:theKey];

        matches = [itemDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        if ([matches isEqualToString:@"cric"])
        {
            matches=[itemDict objectForKey:@"link"];
            break;
        }

    }

    NSString * home=matches;
```

Comment: while i pass like this i got error in MSDATADictionary...is any other way to pass url dynamically???

Answer (score 0):

What is MSDataDictionary? I think it should start with NS not MS.

I searched for MSDataDictionary but didn't get any thing.